# How to add an existing image?

Tags: java, android

I'm editing an open source app: A simple coloring page app for kids. I need to be able to make the user import his own images to be colored,a code for a button in my menu that when clicked by the user it opens his gallery(on SD) to choose an image from and then import this image to the view where he could color it  . [Here is the full source code.](https://f-droid.org/repo/org.androidsoft.coloring_1_src.tar.gz)

And here is the code for loading images from `R.drawable`:

```
public class StartNewActivity extends NoTitleActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    // This is an expensive operation.

    public static int randomOutlineId()
    {
        return new ResourceLoader().randomOutlineId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Apparently this cannot be set from the style.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

        setContentView(R.layout.start_new);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.start_new_grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        setResult(view.getId());
        finish();
    }

    private static class ResourceLoader
    {

        ResourceLoader()
        {
            // Use reflection to list resource ids of thumbnails and outline
            // images.First, we list all the drawables starting with the proper
            // prefixes into 2 maps.
            Map<String, Integer> outlineMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
            Map<String, Integer> thumbMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
            Field[] drawables = R.drawable.class.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < drawables.length; i++)
            {
                String name = drawables[i].getName();
                try
                {
                    if (name.startsWith(PREFIX_OUTLINE))
                    {
                        outlineMap.put(name.substring(PREFIX_OUTLINE.length()),
                                drawables[i].getInt(null));
                    }
                    if (name.startsWith(PREFIX_THUMB))
                    {
                        thumbMap.put(name.substring(PREFIX_THUMB.length()),
                                drawables[i].getInt(null));
                    }
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                }
            }
            Set<String> keys = outlineMap.keySet();
            keys.retainAll(thumbMap.keySet());
            _outlineIds = new Integer[keys.size()];
            _thumbIds = new Integer[keys.size()];
            int j = 0;
            Iterator<String> i = keys.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                String key = i.next();
                _outlineIds[j] = outlineMap.get(key);
                _thumbIds[j] = thumbMap.get(key);
                j++;
            }
        }

        public Integer[] getThumbIds()
        {
            return _thumbIds;
        }

        public Integer[] getOutlineIds()
        {
            return _outlineIds;
        }

        public int randomOutlineId()
        {
            return _outlineIds[new Random().nextInt(_outlineIds.length)];
        }
        private static final String PREFIX_OUTLINE = "outline";
        private static final String PREFIX_THUMB = "thumb";
        private Integer[] _thumbIds;
        private Integer[] _outlineIds;
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            _context = c;
            _resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return _resourceLoader.getThumbIds().length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(_context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(145, 145));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(StartNewActivity.this);
            }
            else
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(_resourceLoader.getThumbIds()[position]);
            imageView.setId(_resourceLoader.getOutlineIds()[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
        private Context _context;
        private ResourceLoader _resourceLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to state exactly what your problem is with your code, and what is the actual thing that you are asking. It is not really clear what answer you expect right now.

Comment: i need a code for my project, this code should allow users to add their own images into the app, then this image is used to as any other image that is already in the R.drawable , and i have not used any code for this as i am new to android developing, i have posted the whole project in the link above if you could please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use pictures from sd card in your application .
You can do so using the following links

[Load images from sd card folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982491/load-images-from-sd-card-folder)

[loading images from SD card directory in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676384/loading-images-from-sd-card-directory-in-gridview)

[How to Dynamically show images from a folder in sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471222/how-to-dynamically-show-images-from-a-folder-in-sdcard?rq=1)

[gridview and setImageBitmap when load image from SDcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026591/gridview-and-setimagebitmap-when-load-image-from-sdcard?rq=1)

Hope it helps